# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null getting this error on laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog

I am using laravel 6.0 and I am getting this strange error "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null" what I have is notification table where I am having notification_id and this notification_id is linked to notification_message table, I am trying to create a realtion between them I tried everything but I am getting this strange error.

Here is my notification Model where i have defined this relationship

```
public function notificationMessage(){
    $this->hasOne('App\Models\NotificationMessage','id');
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't forget to `return` the relationship

```
public function notificationMessage(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\NotificationMessage','id');
}
```

Comment: Yes I think I am missing the return 